# Different between Provider and ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, dart

whats the difference between these 2 widgets and its necessary to use `ChangeNotifier` in every `Provider` or there is many ways to use `Provider`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Provider exposes a value down the widget tree so that children can have access to it, regardless their location (but still, they must be at least one level below the provider). Generally you use a provider to expose a "cache" to a series of widgets or as a neat way of sharing data across multiple pages. Note that:

- By default, when reading a value stored in a provider, nothing happens. It means that if you're exposing a class and you change some internals of it, children won't listen to it.
- If your class exposed via provider mixes with `ChangeNotifier` then you've the possibility to rebuild listeners when something changes.

You are absolutely **not** forced to use `ChangeNotifier` in your model classes exposed by a provider. Use it when you need some widgets to listen to changes but if that's not the case, just ignore it.

---

**Example 1 - (no ChangeNofitier)**

You are using a `TabBarView` to work with tabs (let's say you have 3 pages) and your pages need to share some data. Instead of sharing data using a `Navigator`, which can become cumbersome, go for a provider.

```
class MyDataHolder {
  int _value = 0;

  void updateValue(int a) {
    _value = a;
  }
}
```

And then do something like this:

```
Provider<MyDataHolder>(
  create: (_) => MyDataHolder(),
  child: MyWidgetWithTabs(),
)
```

In this way you can easily share data among pages

**Example 2 - (with ChangeNotifier)**

Still the above case but if you want your pages to listen to changes on a particular data, then use a notifier. Like this:

```
class MyDataHolder with ChangeNotifier {
  int _value = 0;

  void updateValue(int a) {
    _value = a;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Now children listen to changes. Differently from before, when calling `updateValue` listeners will be rebuilt.

---

So both ways are good but they have different purposes. If you don't need a series of listeners to be rebuilt in response to updates, just don't use `ChangeNotifier`.

Comment: must you not additionally use ChangeNotifierProvider<MyDataHolder> instead of Provider<MyDataHolder> for it to react to changes in Example 2?

Comment: the question also included ChangeNotifierProvider, and you didn't mention that class at all in your answer

Comment: For example 2, Provider IMHO also needs to be changed to ChangeNotifierProvider.